# Does someone destroyed by a God of Destruction leave a ghost?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

If someone gets destroyed by a Hakai, does he/she leave a ghost or is that obliterated alongside him/her?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is already in its [wikia page](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Hakai).

> As Gods of Destruction, they possess the power to destroy almost anything with little effort, **even intangible beings such as souls**. **People destroyed by Hakai do not go to Other World and simply cease to exist**. However, in the manga, Beerus admits that Hakai does not work against people who are immortal.

Since the Other World is their equivalent to our afterlife where presumably, our ghost or spirit goes after death, then yes, Hakai can destroy someone including his/her ghost/spirit.

The technique however,

> can be controlled by the user in moderation to not fully destroying the victim.

There are also [a lot of variations](https://dragonball.fandom.com/wiki/Hakai#Variations) of the said technique.

Comment: Is there any specific instance in the anime or manga where it is mentioned that a God of Destruction has the ability to destroy something completely out of existence? As this makes their technique exactly identical to that of the Omni Kings and the fact that a mortal like Goku was able to effortlessly replicate it in the manga seems kind of makes the whole thing seem a little stupid.

Answer (score 2):

No. When Beerus destroyed Zamasu in our time. He destroyed his soul as well. Nothing a destroyer destroyed goes to the after life I think. That’s the way he balances the universe.